# Finding a basis for a vector subspace of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I find the basis for $\{{ax^2+bx+a \mid a,b \in \mathbb{R}\}}$? 
I used to enter the vectors to a matrix and then reduce rows but I don't know what to do now?

Comment: A basis is, by definition, a linearly independent generating set. From the description of the subspace you already get a generating set. Test this for linear independence. If it is linearly dependent then you need to remove unnecessary elements of it until it becomes linearly independent.

Answer (score 1):

$V=\{{ax^2+bx+a : a,b \in \mathbb{R}\}}$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ of functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.

$V$ is generated by the functions $f_1(x)=x^2+1$ and $f_2(x)=x$.

These two functions are linearly independent because they have different degrees.